# calloc() and NULL

Tags: c, null, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I know that calloc allocates memory and writes zeroes to each cell, so my question is:
is there a difference between using calloc or using malloc and running over the cells writing NULL to them? Are the zeroes of calloc equivalent to NULL?

Comment: `NULL` might not `0`(all bits are 0) as a representation.

Comment: Some interesting issues with implementation here - http://locklessinc.com/articles/calloc/

Comment: @BrianAgnew Why doesn't OP in the article simply check for overflow with: `n > SIZE_MAX/size`

Comment: @2501 - I don't know. Perhaps they're simply being concise for the purposes of the article

Comment: What "cells"? The memory allocated `malloc` and `calloc` can be used to store objects of any type. Are you assuming the allocated space will be used to store pointer values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not *always* equivalent, but on most popular machines you'll be fine. `calloc` writes a bit pattern of all-zeros to the allocated memory, but the null pointer value might not be all-bits-zero on some machines (or even just for some types on some machines).

Check out the [Null Pointers](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html) section of the C FAQ for lots and lots of information.

Comment: Updated URL for the Null Pointers section: http://c-faq.com/null/index.html

Comment: Thanks - fixed in the post now, too.

Answer (score 2):

NULL isn't guaranteed to have all bits set to 0, even thought it always compares equal to the integer constant 0.

Calloc will set all of the bits to 0 the same as a memset call would. It is permitted that the resulting value(s) will not compare equal to NULL.

Therefore they are not equivalent.