# Valgrind: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value. Check is null. C

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

I have this code:

```
// list.h

typedef struct Node {
  struct Node *next;
  int *data;
} Node;

typedef struct List {
  Node *head;
} List;

// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "helpers.h"

int main()
{
  // creating list
  List *list = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
  Node *node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  list->head = node;

  // creating 5 empty nodes
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
  {
    node->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node = node->next;
  }

  // trying to fill it if it is empty
  node = list->head;

  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
  {
    if (node->data == NULL)
    {
      node->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
      *(node->data) = 1;
    }
  }

  // freeing
  node = list->head;
  Node *tmp;
  while (node != NULL)
  {
    free(node->data);
    tmp = node;
    node = node->next;
    free(tmp);
  }

  free(list);
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to use valgrind and this is what he tells:

```
==340== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==340==    at 0x10870A: main (main1.c:24)
```

I don't strictly need to have something inside node, so my list can be like this `[1,1, null, 1, null]`. But then in the code I want to use if statement to check if `node->data` is already exists (this is a pointer, so I have to check if memory allocated and data points to some value).

To be honest my program is working somehow (it is more complicated than this example code I showed, but the valgrind error is similar), but I think something goes wrong anyway.

Comment: Okay, I'll tell you what my program has to do. I have a list with n elements. But I don't strictly need to have something inside element, so my list can be like this [1,1, null, 1, null]. So I guess it is not malloc/calloc problem, but mb I am wrong..

Comment: As well as never initializing any `node->data` items, you don't set `node->next` for the last node either

Comment: `if (node->data == NULL)` -- `node->data` was never initialized. There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @David C. Rankin, @M.M
*```node->data``` was never initialized*
But it is exist by default in struct node, isn't it?

Comment: Code does not really matter (I mean main.c code), the main question related to List using. If my list looks like I have already written, how to check if node->data is NULL at the moment.

Comment: It is an *uninitialized pointer* at the time you check `if (node->data == NULL)` -- Bad Juju... When you allocate a list node *Always* initialize the elements. E.g. `Node *node = malloc (sizeof *node); if (!node) { perror ("malloc-node"); return 1; }; node->data = NULL; node->next = NULL;`. That way you are never faced with either of these problems. (also consider adding a `tail` pointer to your `list` struct so there is no need to iterate to the last node for insertions)

Comment: [Single Linked LIst Example w/tail Pointer](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A)

Comment: @user3386109 `calloc()` isn't guaranteed to initialize pointers to `NULL`, only integer types.

Comment: @ВладимирГоворухин If you want a list like `[1,1,null,1,null]` then you must set `node->data` to NULL after the `malloc`. The memory that `malloc` returns is not initialized, so your code needs to initialize it.

Comment: @Barmar calloc isn't...  uh, try again.   Calloc zeroes.   NULL is a pretty name for 0.  pointers within calloc are nulled.

Comment: @mevets It sets the data to the zero representation, but that doesn't have to be the representation of the null pointer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800636/calloc-and-null

Comment: Yes, NULL could be -1, but so much code would fail you would never have the fun of experiencing it.

Answer (score 1):

you must terminate your linked list with a NULL, so after creation the last node should `lastnode->next == NULL`, therefore when done creating you must initialise it with NULL `lastnode->next = NULL;`